# Sorting column names to be ascending after pivoting

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Spark dataframe which looks like this:

```
+----+-----+-------------+---+
|year|month|feature      |cnt|
+----+-----+-------------+---+
|2019|2    |Feature1     |2  |
|2019|2    |Feature2     |5  |
|2019|2    |Feature3     |54 |
|2019|2    |Feature4     |75 |
|2019|2    |...          |1  |
|2019|2    |...          |85 |
|2019|2    |...          |77 |
|2019|2    |...          |124|
|2019|2    |...          |6  |
|2019|2    |...          |362|
|2019|2    |...          |74 |
|2019|2    |...          |10 |
|2019|3    |Feature1     |10 |
|2019|3    |Feature2     |5  | 
...
```

I can successfully convert the dataframe to Pandas and pivot the combination of year + month to be columns:

```
monthly_df = monthly_counts.toPandas()
monthly_df['yearM'] = monthly_df['year'].astype(str) + monthly_df['month'].astype(str)
del monthly_df['year']
del monthly_df['month']

monthly_pv = pd.pivot_table(monthly_df, values = 'cnt', index=['feature'], columns='yearM').reset_index()
monthly_pv
```

The problem is that the column order becomes like so (despite the original dataframe being sorted asc):

```
yearM | feature | 201910 | 201911 | 201912 | 20192 | 20193 | 20194 | 20195 | 20196 | 20197 ...
```

Is that anyway that I can have the column names sorted asc in the pivoted table? I.e. the first column after `feature` would be `20192` followed by `20193` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you name the columns in a way that make them alphabetically sorted in the wrong order. `20191` will be followed by `201910`, `201911`, `201912` then `20192`. To solve it, you can add a zero to the single-digit months:

```
monthly_df = monthly_counts.toPandas().assign(day=1)
monthly_df['yearM'] = pd.to_datetime(monthly_df[['year','month','day']]).dt.strftime('%Y%m')
del monthly_df['year']
del monthly_df['month']
del monthly_df['day']

monthly_pv = pd.pivot_table(monthly_df, values = 'cnt', index=['feature'], columns='yearM').reset_index()
monthly_pv
```

Comment: I seem to run into a ValueError with this: `extra keys have been passed to the datetime assemblage: [cnt,feature]`